# Salvar cookie da visita na página

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, view

Olá estou usando um código php mysql que conta as visitas de cada página, porém sempre que a página é atualizada ele adiciona mais uma visita, gostaria de uma ajuda com meu código para que ele salve o cookie por um determinado tempo antes do contar uma nova visita.

PS: cada página está salva no BD e tem visualizações distintas

Código das paginas:

```
<?php 
//Aqui pegamos o id da página
$idDaPagina = $explode[1];

//Busca na tabela o numero de vezes que a página ja foi visitada
$busca = "SELECT * FROM contador WHERE idPagina = '$idDaPagina'";
$exe = mysqli_query($conectar,$busca);

$resultado_vist = (mysqli_fetch_array($exe));

//Pega o numero de visistas que consta na tabela, adiciona mais um e atualiza
$visitantes = $resultado_vist['visitas'] + 1;
$altera = "UPDATE contador SET visitas = '$visitantes' WHERE idPagina = '$idDaPagina'";
$exe1 = mysqli_query($conectar,$altera);

//Faz uma nova busca e retorna o numero de visitas depois da atualização
$exe = mysqli_query($conectar,$busca);
$total = (mysqli_fetch_array($exe));
$visitas = $total['visitas'];

?>

No espaço do conteudo dou um <?php echo $visitas; ?>
```

Desde já Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode trabalhar com cookies, defina o tempo necessário dele e quando expirar, você adiciona +1 ao contador. Seria o seguinte código:

```
// Define em horas quanto tempo vai durar cada cookie
$hours = 1;

// Comando para setar o cookie
setcookie("contador", true, time() + (3600 * $hours));

// Verificação do cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE["contador"]) && $_COOKIE['contador'] == true ) {
    // Faz nada...
} else {
    // Logica para adicionar mais 1 a visitas de páginas
}
```

Comment: ai entra outro problema, não posso usar o setcookie nas minhas páginas contando as visitas individualmente porque uso url amigável, minha index tem o cabeçalho e rodapé e só recebe os conteúdos que estão nas outras páginas, e como eu tenho que usar o cookie antes de qualquer html ele registra uma unica visita.

Comment: Basta você utilizar a string do cookei concatenada com o id da sua página. Exemplo "contador-id-" . $idDaPagina. Assim cada cookie vai valer para cada página de modo distinto.